# Using multiple WSDLs with Axis2 wsdl2code Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, code-generation, apache-axis, wsdl2code

I'm creating a client with Maven2 that uses several web services.  I'm restricted to using `Axis2` or other framework supporting Apache `HttpClient` as an HTTP conduit because these services require integration with a managed certificate solution based on `HttpClient`.

I'm familiar with CXF's code-gen Maven plugin which allows multiple WSDLs to be input during code generation.  However, the Axis2 code-gen plugin can process only one WSDL at a time.

How can I make Maven run `wsdl2code` for each WSDL during code-gen phase?  Do I need multiple profiles for this?

The build section of POM looks like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <unpackClasses>true</unpackClasses>
                <databindingName>adb</databindingName>
                <packageName>org.example.stackoverflow.axis2-maven</packageName>
                <!-- only one of these actually gets used by code generator -->
                <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/service1.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/service2.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                <syncMode>sync</syncMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

#### References

- [Maven2 WSDL2Code Plug-in Guide](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/maven-plugins/maven-wsdl2code-plugin.html)
- [wsdl2code command line tool](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/CodegenToolReference.html)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can try with this, i could not test it right now but i think should work

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>ws1</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                   <unpackClasses>true</unpackClasses>
                   <databindingName>adb</databindingName>
                   <packageName>org.example.stackoverflow.axis2-maven</packageName>
                   <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/service1.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                   <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                   <syncMode>sync</syncMode>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>ws2</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                   <unpackClasses>true</unpackClasses>
                   <databindingName>adb</databindingName>
                   <packageName>org.example.stackoverflow.axis2-maven</packageName>
                   <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/service2.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                   <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                   <syncMode>sync</syncMode>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Yea, that did it, thanks.  Note that POM didn't validate as is.  I got: `You cannot have two plugin executions with the same (or missing) <id/> elements.` message.  After adding a unique `<id>` to each execution, it was all good.

Comment: What if I have 50 WSDL's that needs to be generated. Is this possible using the maven plugin ?

Comment: how can I change the output directory location to src/main/java/.. When I am doing it, it is changing the packageName and makes it src.org.example............  How can I resolve this?

Comment: @AppleBud For the sources directory use the `${project.build.sourceDirectory}` property; however, it is not an healthy practice to generate stuff in the sources directory during the build process. So you better turn off the automatic generation in the `generate-sources` phase, by using ` <phase>never</phase>` in the execution configuration, and then invoke the goal directly when needed.

Comment: okie, thanks. Is there any way I can make my pom.xml to skip a particular goal?

Comment: @AppleBud `goal`s are only executed when they are bound to `phase`s defined in the maven build life-cycle. By default, axis2-maven plugin binds to the generate-sources phase, so it get executed. To unbind it, as i said, and assuming you are using maven 3, just use <phase/> or <phase>never</phase> (never is a non-existing phase) like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800647/in-a-maven-multi-module-project-how-can-i-disable-a-plugin-in-one-child

Answer (score 1):

i know that is a old question but there is another way to risolve this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>ws1</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/service1.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>ws2</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/service2.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <unpackClasses>true</unpackClasses>
                <databindingName>adb</databindingName>
                <packageName>org.example.stackoverflow.axis2-maven</packageName>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                <syncMode>sync</syncMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

with that way you have a unique configuration for all wsdl