# In a Maven multi-module project, how can I disable a plugin in one child?

Tags: maven, plugins, reporting, dependency-management

I have a maven multi-module project (boy, I've written that opening *way* too many times on this site).  Almost all the modules (that is, the ones that have *code* in them) should run the maven-site-plugin to generate reports about code coverage, etc.  These have a detailed shared configuration -- which reports to run, which files to cover/exclude for certain plugins, etc.

However, there are a few modules that deal with packaging -- running the assembly plugin to generate a tarball, etc.  These gain nothing from running a site report -- there's no code to analyze, no tests to report on.

So I have a lot of modules that need to **share plugin configuration**, and a few modules that need to **not run the plugin**, preferably at all.  I can do the former (share configuration) if I put the plugin in the `<build>` section of the parent POM, but I can't seem to turn off the plugin when I need to in this case.  I can do the latter (avoid running the plugin) if I push configuration down to each module's own POM, but I can't figure out a good way to share the configuration information in this case.

Is what I want -- shared configuration, for a plugin that's sometimes disabled by a child module -- even possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

By "run the plugin", I'm assuming you mean that the plugin is bound to a lifecycle phase, and you'd like to unbind it in some modules. First, you could consider changing your POM inheritance so that the modules that don't need the plugins have one parent and the ones that do have a different parent. If you don't want to do that, then you can explicitly set the execution phase to "nothing" in a child module. E.g. if you had a parent pom configuration like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>i-do-something</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                ... lots of configuration
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then in a child module, you could do this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>i-do-something</id>
            <phase/>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Because it's the same plugin and the same execution id, it overrides the configuration specified in the parent, and now the plugin isn't bound to a phase in the child project.

Comment: Awesome, I knew it would be something like that, but I'm still kind of a yellow-belt (in case you hadn't guessed from the trail of Maven questions in my recent history).  I can't move the projects to different parents because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589931/how-should-i-share-maven-depdendencymanagement-from-multiple-sources), but I will unbind the report plugin.  Thanks!

Comment: This approach doesn't work if there's no `<phase>` specified for the plugin in parent module.

Comment: @evgeniysharapov You can still use `<phase>none</phase>` in the child module in that case, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14653088/1155724).

Answer (score 3):

Ryan Stewart's answer works if execution that you wish to suppress in the parent pom is tagged with an `id`.  If, however, the parent pom doesn't tag the execution with an `id` (and, of course, you can't edit that parent pom) then I found that doing the following suppresses the parent pom's action.

1. First set the phase of the execution to `none`
2. Create another execution, give it an `id` and do in it what you need it to do.
3. run `mvn help:effective-pom` to confirm that it has correctly suppressed what you needed suppressed from the parent pom.

Here's an example:
This is how my parent pom looked like:

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <inherited>true</inherited>
    </plugin>
```

I needed to change the goal to `jar-no-fork`.  Note that the execution in parent pom doesn't have an `id` that I could use to disable it.  So here's what added to my child pom:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

As a result this is how the effective-pom looks like:

```
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>none</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <compress>false</compress>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <compress>false</compress>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <compress>false</compress>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

This ensured that the goal `jar` never runs and only the goal `jar-no-fork` executes -- which is what I wanted to achieve.