# Disable a Maven plugin defined in a parent POM

Tags: maven, maven-2

I am using a parent POM that defines a plugin that I do not want to be run in a child POM. How can I disable the plugin in the child pom completely?

Constraint: I cannot change the parent POM itself.

Answer (score 261, accepted):

The following works for me when disabling Findbugs in a child POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>ID_AS_IN_PARENT</id> <!-- id is necessary sometimes -->
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note: the full definition of the Findbugs plugin is in our parent/super POM, so it'll inherit the version and so-on.

In Maven 3, you'll need to use:

```
 <configuration>
      <skip>true</skip>
 </configuration>
```

for the plugin.

Comment: While this is "correct" i.e. it works it should be noted that it's an unspecified (or at least _undocumented_) feature. There's no official phase called 'none'. So, you might as well put 'foo' there.

Comment: For me in Maven 3 this doesn't work. <skip>true</skip> like bmargulies suggested works

Comment: I had to add the `<id>…</id>` part of the parent POM, then it worked for me.

Comment: The Maven 3 solution doesn't really disable the plugin though, does it? According to the output, the plugin is still executed. Whether it then respects the skip configuration, and how/what it chooses to skip, appears to be up to the individual plugin.

Comment: How have the enforcer plugin and it's finding duplicates in my test dependencies; which I don't care about. How can I tell it to not run on anything that's a test dependency

Comment: mirabilos's comment is the correct solution for Maven 3 and is portable across all plugins. Not all plugins have a `<skip>` parameter.

Answer (score 78):

See if the plugin has a 'skip' configuration parameter. Nearly all do. if it does, just add it to a declaration in the child:

```
    <plugin>
       <groupId>group</groupId>
       <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
       <configuration>
         <skip>true</skip>
       </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

If not, then use:

```
<plugin>    
    <groupId>group</groupId>   
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>    
    <executions>
         <execution>
           <id>TheNameOfTheRelevantExecution</id>
           <phase>none</phase>
         </execution>    
    </executions>  
</plugin>
```

Comment: How about naming the plugin you are working with, and running help:effective-pom to see if you really have the execution correct.

Comment: Also look out for plugins versus pluginManagement. The later overrides the former.

Comment: I am using the Cobertura plugin and I do not want to run it in the child pom.

Comment: The check goal has a skip in 2.5. It didn't before. The cobertura goal does not.

Comment: I don't want to skip just the check but the whole plugin execution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4384/discussion-between-tob-and-bmargulies)

Comment: No, let's move this to user@mojo.codehaus.org. There are more people there who can help and it's a better place to do tech support.

Comment: I also tried both options with `tomcat7-maven-plugin` but neither worked

Comment: First option worked to disable the running of maven-dependency-plugin that was in the parent pom. Using maven 3.5.2 + java 8

Comment: Important note for those, who use **Tiles Maven Plugin** and considering to use second option (override execution by ID): the plugin [changes execution IDs](https://github.com/repaint-io/maven-tiles#execution-ids) inside the tile to reflect tile GAV coordinates. So in order for override to work `<configuration tiles-keep-id="true" />` tag should be added to the execution to preserve specified execution ID.

Comment: Using skip=true doesn't work for me. I want to disable "checkstyle" plugin in "io.confluent:common" but your solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 40):

The thread is old, but maybe someone is still interested.
The shortest form I found is further improvement on the example from λlex and bmargulies. The execution tag will look like:

```
<execution>
    <id>TheNameOfTheRelevantExecution</id>
    <phase/>
</execution>
```

2 points I want to highlight:

1. phase is set to nothing, which looks less hacky than 'none', though still a hack.
2. id must be the same as execution you want to override. If you don't specify id for execution, Maven will do it implicitly (in a way not expected intuitively by you).

After posting found it is already in stackoverflow:
[In a Maven multi-module project, how can I disable a plugin in one child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800647/in-a-maven-multi-module-project-how-can-i-disable-a-plugin-in-one-child)

Comment: For the record: the default execution IDs follow simple rules that are laid out in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34599117/7641

Comment: It is worth noting that this solution actually **disables** (as OP asked for) the plugin (for the given execution ID) instead of relying on a plugin-specific "skip" option.

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is really old but the solution from @Ivan Bondarenko helped me in my situation.

I had the following in my `pom.xml`.

```
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
                <groupId>com.consol.citrus</groupId>
                <artifactId>citrus-remote-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${citrus.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-citrus-war</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-war</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What I wanted, was to disable the execution of `generate-citrus-war` for a specific profile and this was the solution:

```
<profile>
    <id>it</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.consol.citrus</groupId>
                <artifactId>citrus-remote-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${citrus.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- disable generating the war for this profile -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-citrus-war</id>
                        <phase/>
                    </execution>

                    <!-- do something else -->
                    <execution>
                        ...
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```