# How to disable nexus-staging-maven-plugin in sub-modules

Tags: maven, nexus

I'm looking into replacing the maven-deploy-plugin with the nexus-staging-maven-plugin.

Now some of the sub-modules of my project (e.g. integration test modules) are not to be deployed to the Nexus server. I used to disable the deployment of these modules via the "maven.deploy.skip" property. I cannot find anything comparable for the nexus-staging-maven-plugin, though. Is there another way for skipping single modules from deployment using this plug-in?

I also tried to bind the plug-in to the pseudo phase "none" as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821152/disable-a-maven-plugin-defined-in-a-parent-pom), but examining the effective POM, there is still the injected execution of the plug-in (I assume that's due to the way how it replaces the existing deploy plug-in).

Comment: The common solutions are to skip staging (see the accepted answer), but if you skip staging in the last submodule it skips all staging (a serious error in the design of the plugin that has been closed "wontfix" - https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-9138). The backup solution to that problem is to skip the deploy phase in the submodule. I have a situation where I want to deploy the artifact of my last submodule, but not publish it to nexus (it's a war file). The only solution I've found to this is to add a dummy node at the end of the submodule list.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the configuration property `skipNexusStagingDeployMojo` of a given submodule to true. See more configuration properties documented in [the Nexus book chapter about deployment to staging](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/staging-deployment.html).

Comment: This way the artifacts will not get deployed at all if last module/submodule in reactor is skipped. Did not find a way to tell the nexus-staging-maven-plugin to deploy it anyway. Any hints? I do want do skip deployment of two submodules with examples only (visible only as a source).

Comment: Just set the config parameter only in the modules you want to be skipped and not in the parent..

Comment: That's exactly what I did. No success.

Comment: any progress on this? I have the same problem that all modules are skipped. Here's my project https://github.com/AKSW/RDFUnit

Comment: This is a sonatype bug, see here for details https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-9138

Comment: Although not an optimal solution, what I did was to try to move at least one "deployable" module after the skipped module, so it's not any more the last module.

Comment: This bug , that cannot skip specific module , it waste me a whole afternoon.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I found to deal the limitations of nexus-staging-maven-plugin is to isolate any module you do not want to deploy into a separate Maven profile, and exclude it when a deploy occurs. Example:

```
<profile>
    <id>no-deploy</id>
    <!--
    According to https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-maven-plugins/tree/master/staging/maven-plugin
    skipNexusStagingDeployMojo may not be set to true in the last reactor module. Because we don't
    want to deploy our last module, nor a dummy module, we simply omit the relevant modules when
    a deploy is in progress.
    -->
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>!deploy</name>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <modules>
        <module>test</module>
        <module>benchmark</module>
    </modules>
</profile>
```

In the above example, I avoid building and deploying the "test" and "benchmark" modules. If you want to run unit tests without deploying them, use separate runs:

```
mvn test
mvn -Ddeploy deploy
```

Comment: Did you mean "-Pdeploy"? According to https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html you can activate a profile by using the "-P" flag

Comment: @BenMcCann No, I meant `-Ddeploy`. You could use `-Pno-deploy` as you suggest, but in my project I want to active one profile when `deploy` is true and another project when `deploy` is false. Using `-Pdeploy` and `-Pno-deploy` would work but seems needlessly verbose to me. Either approach is valid though.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar problem. Solution that worked for me was adding deployment plugin with skip as true in modules that need to be excluded from deploy task.

```
           <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because all other answers did not quite work for my setup, I endend up with a setup where you can explicitly disable all, but the main module (or in any other combination you like).

Add the followin profile to your main pom

```xml
    <!-- this is a workaround to be able to only deploy the main module used in deploy phase, nexus stage plugin is buggy -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>allmodules</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <modules>
                <module>modules/module1</module>
                <module>modules/module2</module>
                <module>modules/module3</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>mainmodule</id>
            <modules>
                <module>modules/module1</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

In this example you only want to deploy the artifact from `module1` and you have 3 modules: `module1`, `module2` and `module3`. Since all modules are active by default, are "normal" maven targets should behave as before. To deploy simply do:

```bash
mvn verify nexus-staging:deploy -P !allmodules,mainmodule
```

which deactivates the `allmodules` profile, while activating the `mainmodule`.