# nexus-staging-maven-plugin only upload artifacts that are explicitly set NOT to be uploaded

Tags: maven, sonatype, maven-deploy-plugin

I'm deploying my project to maven central but encounter this quirky behaviour of nexus-staging-maven-plugin

this is my project structure:

```
spookystuff (want to release pom)
|-spookystuff-core (want to release jar)
|-spookystuff-example(DON'T want to release)
|-spookystuff-integration(DON'T want to release)
\-spookystuff-assembly(DON'T want to release)
```

To achieve this I setup nexus-staging-maven-plugin in parent maven pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and disabled it in example, integration and assembly modules:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skipStaging>true</skipStaging>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

However when I execute mvn deploy:

```
mvn clean deploy -DskipTests=true -Dgpg.passphrase=******
```

I encounter this very quirky behaviour, the plugin pretty much reversed my intention: it refuse to upload what should be uploaded and upload what should not be uploaded:

```
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-assembly/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-assembly-0.3.1.1.jar
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-assembly/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-assembly-0.3.1.1.jar (12 KB at 31.1 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-assembly/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-assembly-0.3.1.1.pom
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-assembly/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-assembly-0.3.1.1.pom (5 KB at 22.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-assembly/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-assembly/maven-metadata.xml (361 B at 2.6 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-assembly/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-assembly/maven-metadata.xml (361 B at 1.9 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-integration/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-integration-0.3.1.1.jar
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-integration/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-integration-0.3.1.1.jar (2 KB at 4.3 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-integration/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-integration-0.3.1.1.pom
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-integration/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-integration-0.3.1.1.pom (2 KB at 8.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-integration/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-integration/maven-metadata.xml (364 B at 2.8 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-integration/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-integration/maven-metadata.xml (364 B at 1.6 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-example/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-example-0.3.1.1.jar
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-example/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-example-0.3.1.1.jar (259 KB at 474.5 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-example/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-example-0.3.1.1.pom
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-example/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-example-0.3.1.1.pom (5 KB at 24.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-example/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-example/maven-metadata.xml (360 B at 2.9 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-example/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-example/maven-metadata.xml (360 B at 1.9 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-integration/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-integration-0.3.1.1.pom.asc
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-integration/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-integration-0.3.1.1.pom.asc (473 B at 7.6 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-assembly/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-assembly-0.3.1.1-javadoc.jar
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-assembly/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-assembly-0.3.1.1-javadoc.jar (373 KB at 459.8 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-integration/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-integration-0.3.1.1.jar.asc
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-integration/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-integration-0.3.1.1.jar.asc (473 B at 3.6 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-assembly/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-assembly-0.3.1.1.jar.asc
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-assembly/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-assembly-0.3.1.1.jar.asc (473 B at 3.6 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-example/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-example-0.3.1.1.jar.asc
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-example/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-example-0.3.1.1.jar.asc (473 B at 1.3 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-example/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-example-0.3.1.1-javadoc.jar
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-example/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-example-0.3.1.1-javadoc.jar (477 KB at 645.3 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-assembly/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-assembly-0.3.1.1.pom.asc
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-assembly/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-assembly-0.3.1.1.pom.asc (473 B at 6.2 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-example/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-example-0.3.1.1.pom.asc
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-example/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-example-0.3.1.1.pom.asc (473 B at 6.5 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-example/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-example-0.3.1.1-javadoc.jar.asc
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-example/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-example-0.3.1.1-javadoc.jar.asc (473 B at 7.3 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-assembly/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-assembly-0.3.1.1-javadoc.jar.asc
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-assembly/0.3.1.1/spookystuff-assembly-0.3.1.1-javadoc.jar.asc (473 B at 7.2 KB/sec)
[INFO]  * Bulk deploy of locally gathered snapshot artifacts finished.
```

To make things even more spooky, I checked sonatype nexus as a maven central repository browser, and cannot find any of these files! The only artifact remain is an older version which I uploaded 2 days ago.

Can some one explain why I encounter 3 quirky behaviour in a row?

Answer (score 2):

A late reply, but I thought I'd answer since this was the first post I found when I ran into similar issues.  I got the answer from a comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305850/how-to-disable-nexus-staging-maven-plugin-in-sub-modules)

I think the problem is related to [this bug](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-9138).  You can solve it by making sure that the last module listed in your parent pom configuration is one that you *do* want to be released.

That's what fixed a very similar issue for me, anyway.