# nexus-staging-maven-plugin refuse to upload after deferred deployment

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, nexus

I have a multi-module project that has nexus-staging-maven-plugin configured in parent pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                <!--<autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

By default it should be inherited by all submodules (except those disabled using technique in [How to disable nexus-staging-maven-plugin in sub-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305850/how-to-disable-nexus-staging-maven-plugin-in-sub-modules))

However, when I start deployment:

```
mvn clean deploy -DskipTests=true -Prelease-sign-artifacts -Dgpg.passphrase=*****
```

I see the following message:

```
[INFO] Installing Nexus Staging features:
[INFO]   ... total of 5 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with nexus-staging-maven-plugin
```

...

```
[INFO] --- nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.6:deploy (injected-nexus-deploy) @ spookystuff-core ---
[INFO] Performing deferred deploys (gathering into "/home/peng/git/spookystuff/target/nexus-staging/deferred")...
[INFO] Installing /home/peng/git/spookystuff/core/target/spookystuff-core-0.3.2-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/peng/git/spookystuff/target/nexus-staging/deferred/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/spookystuff-core/0.3.2-SNAPSHOT/spookystuff-core-0.3.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

...

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
```

...

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

No upload happens whatsoever. The artifact that should be uploaded to nexus were still cached under:

/target/nexus-staging/deferred

but neither the log nor nexus server record indicates that it has been uploaded. What has been wrong here and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Do you have skipNexusStagingDeployMojo defined in any of your modules?  We just found a bug where if it is set in the last module in the reactor it stops the deploy: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-9138

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I did, how did you find that?

Comment: Also please copy it to the answer so I can make it official

Comment: I've tested and confirmed your answer. Could you copy-paste your comment as an new answer so I can reward you with points?