# maven-pmd-plugin disable for one module

Tags: maven, pmd

I'm trying to disable execution of maven-pmd-plugin for one of maven project module, but can't find a working solution. 
Right now I have the next in the module:

```
    <properties>
      <cpd.skip>true</cpd.skip>
      <pmd.skip>true</pmd.skip>
      <maven.pmd.enable>false</maven.pmd.enable>
      <maven.pmd.cpd.enable>false</maven.pmd.cpd.enable>
    </properties>
```

And have the next in the debug output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-pmd-plugin:3.2:cpd (pmd-cpd) @ module ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.2:cpd from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.2, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6e70c242]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.2:cpd' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) aggregate = false
[DEBUG]   (f) compileSourceRoots = [/cicd/module/src/main/java]
[DEBUG]   (f) format = xml
[DEBUG]   (f) ignoreIdentifiers = false
[DEBUG]   (f) ignoreLiterals = false
[DEBUG]   (f) includeTests = false
[DEBUG]   (f) includeXmlInSite = false
[DEBUG]   (f) linkXRef = true
[DEBUG]   (f) minimumTokens = 100
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = /cicd/module/target/site
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = true
[DEBUG]   (f) skipEmptyReport = true
[DEBUG]   (f) targetDirectory = /cicd/module/target
[DEBUG]   (f) testSourceRoots = [/cicd/module/src/test/java]
[DEBUG]   (f) xrefLocation = /cicd/module/target/site/xref
[DEBUG]   (f) xrefTestLocation = /cicd/module/target/site/xref-test
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Exclusions: **/*~,**/#*#,**/.#*,**/%*%,**/._*,**/CVS,**/CVS/**,**/.cvsignore,**/RCS,**/RCS/**,**/SCCS,**/SCCS/**,**/vssver.scc,**/project.pj,**/.svn,**/.svn/**,**/.arch-ids,**/.arch-ids/**,**/.bzr,**/.bzr/**,**/.MySCMServerInfo,**/.DS_Store,**/.metadata,**/.metadata/**,**/.hg,**/.hg/**,**/.git,**/.gitignore,**/.gitattributes,**/.git/**,**/BitKeeper,**/BitKeeper/**,**/ChangeSet,**/ChangeSet/**,**/_darcs,**/_darcs/**,**/.darcsrepo,**/.darcsrepo/**,**/-darcs-backup*,**/.darcs-temp-mail
[DEBUG] Inclusions: **/*.java
[DEBUG] Searching for files in directory /cicd/module/src/main/java
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding ANSI_X3.4-1968, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[DEBUG] Executing CPD...
```

I'm wondering why does it execute if skip=true 
According to the official [FAQ](http://maven.apache.org/archives/maven-1.x/plugins/pmd/faq.html#disable-subproject) I need to "Simply put maven.pmd.enable=false into your project properties for that one sub-project." Probably I have not correctly put that into the pom. Is it just <properties> in module pom file?

-Dpmd.skip=true -Dcpd.skip=true gives the same result

Comment: No, PMD doesn't use default properties for those values. The default value is a plain "false" not a reference to a property, and `pmd.skip` and `cpd.skip` are User Properties (passed in with `-D`). Those properties will have no effect all by themselves. You should override the configuration of the submodule and set the properties yourself. I'm intrigued non the less you say "-Dpmd.skip=true -Dcpd.skip=true gives the same result", it shouldn't...

Answer (score 5):

If you want to disable a maven module, you have configure pmd in that module. And then exclude all.
Like this:

```html
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <analysisCache>true</analysisCache>
     <!-- enable incremental analysis -->
     <excludes>
      <exclude>**/**</exclude>
     </excludes>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

Maven multimodul-documentation  [;hier](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html)
describes, that configuration in submodules override top level pom definition.

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution, look at [Disable a Maven plugin defined in a parent POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821152/disable-a-maven-plugin-defined-in-a-parent-pom).

This way you disable the plugin so it is not run at all for the module, so nothing gets generated so this way the build time will also dcrease.