# How to ignore a Maven goal in one child?

Tags: maven

I have a parent POM with two children, one of which knows how to jboss-as:deploy, and the other does not.

How do I create a configuration where I can run the deploy goal on the parent pom so that one of the children ignores it?

UPDATE: Thanks to the first two commenters, both remarks seem to be spot on.
Will check how to rewrite the parent pom properly, in the meantime <skip>true<skip> worked like a charm.

Comment: Probably the same way as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821152/disable-a-maven-plugin-defined-in-a-parent-pom

Comment: That sound like wrongly defined the execution of the plugin in the parent instead of only defining the version and really executing in the appropriate child.