# Maven plugin MOJO API in term of parameters

Tags: maven, build, pom.xml, maven-plugin, mojo

From my understanding
the MOJO relative to the compile goal of the maven-compiler-plugin
defines its own parameters,just like any other MOJO plugins.

For example it should have a parameter defined somewhat like the following:

```
/** @parameter default-value="${project.build.sourceDirectory}" */
private String sDir;
```

So these parameters definitions represent a kind of API for the MOJO,
that we can set in various way, mainly from the execution tag.

Please,correct me if I'm wrong.

My question is: 
Where can I filed the API fefinition of the standard maven plugin,
in term of those parameters?

Answer (score 0):

A MOJO (or be more accurate) a goal of a plugin can define the parameter as it likes (or what the plugin author has in mind). Yes this means it's is a kind of an API which is accessed via the pom.xml via the `configuration` tag of the plugin or sometimes via command line (in case of special goals).

For every plugin you can find the documentation online like for example for the maven-compiler-plugin where you can find here the appropriate parameters:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html

Any of the plugins which are located in the groupId: org.apache.maven.plugins you can find it via this overview:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

and you can access the linke `goals` on the page where you find the list of available goals a plugin has and if you go to the link you will find all the parameters.

Apart from that you should take a look here:

- https://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html
- https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html

For things which can be used in the defaultValue you can take a look here:

- https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.html

Comment: Thank you ! one more question please: In the super pom I can see the parameter <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory> wich I think should be used by the compiler:compile goal, why I don't see it in the link you provided ?

Comment: Because it's not part of the configuration for a plugin. This is a general part of the Maven pom which shouldn't be changed at all...Furthermore you can get such information via MavenProject (or MavenSession I'm not sure at the moment)...

Comment: So it looks like that in the MOJO the expression ${project.build.sourceDirectory} is resolved and used but it is not fed to the plugin into a parameter ?

Comment: Sure you can do such things but it's not a good idea cause you can get that via MavenProject etc. Why are you asking in this direction? Purpose?

Comment: @khamarbaise I want to gain more understanding in how maven applies Conventions over configurations:  For example why the compiler maven plugin has not any required parameter for the goal compile? how do we change the default location of source code ? I know it is not advisable I'm just asking to try to understand maven better.