# MAVEN3: how to disable emma-maven-plugin in child project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, emma

I have a parent pom.xml that defines the emma-maven-plugin with inherited=true.

```
<reporting>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.site.version}</version>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${emma.maven.version}</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
         </plugin>
</plugins>
</reporting>
```

However I have a child pom.xml that does not contain any tests. So I tried adding this... execution none, inherited false and skip true to skip the emma report generation, but it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.sonatype.maven.plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${emma.maven.version}</version>            
      <inherited>false</inherited>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>               
        <skip>true</skip>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.sonatype.maven.plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${emma.maven.version}</version>            
      <inherited>false</inherited>
      <configuration>               
        <skip>true</skip>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: try following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821152/disable-a-maven-plugin-defined-in-a-parent-pom

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to not instrument certain package and thus not creating coverage.em thus not creating EMMA report.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${emma.maven.version}</version>            
    <configuration>
      <filters>
        <filter>-com.package.*</filter>
      </filters>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
   </build>
```