# Stop spring boot from executing failsafe plugin

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a spring boot application.

The sprinboot pom is added as a parent

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

This is the failsafe dependency mentioned under `<pluginmanagement>` section in the spring-boot-starter-parent-2.1.2

```
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory</classesDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

I also have a failsafe defined in my project build phase under a different profile.
All my IT files end with 'IT'.

```
        <profile>
            <id>myProfile</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.22.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <groups>${it.groups}</groups>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

When I run `mvn integration-test -PmyProfile`, 
maven starts running the default failsafe execution mentioned in the spring dependency first. And then it runs the plugin from my pom.

That is causing my Integration tests to run twice.

I dont want the IT to be run using the failsafe plugin mentioned in the spring pom.

How do I do that ? 
I dont want to redefine the plugin in my pom.

I just want to remove the goals mentioned in the spring-starter pom.xml

Comment: Please post your full pom file. Furthermore how have you named your tests?

Comment: Edited to answer your questions. Full pom file would be huge. I have posted the relevant lines

Comment: Pretty sure that having the plugin in the `pluginmanagement` is the problem. If you only want it to run when you call your profile you only need the configuration in the profile.

Comment: Yes. But how do I get rid of that plugin coming from pluginmanagement ? That is defined in the springboot pom and I have included that as parent pom

Comment: Found the solution. My <execution> had an <id> and thats why springboot did not merge it with the default run.

Answer (score 0):

I see you found a solution to your problem. You can ignore the parent plugin as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821152/disable-a-maven-plugin-defined-in-a-parent-pom).

Note **`<phase>none</phase>`**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Calling profile myProfile will run and act as expected.