# Why maven-resources-plugin ignores my charset encoding setting?

Tags: java, maven, encoding, ebcdic, maven-resources-plugin

I have a java artifact dual-built for both linux & IBM mainframe, all the dependent shell scripts (in /sbin dir) are initially written in ASCII but are copied to another directory (in /sbin-ebcdic). So I configure the maven-resources-plugin to do it for me:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-sbin</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/sbin-ebcdic</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/sbin</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                        <encoding>IBM037</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

While it does copy the entire directory, all files in them are still in UTF-8 encoding, as if my:

```
<encoding>IBM037</encoding>
```

setting doesn't exist. Why the maven-resources-plugin doesn't function as intended? Is it a bug?

Comment: Please be noted that resource filtering is disabled so this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327003/wrong-encoding-after-activating-resource-filtering is out of the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation carefully of [resources:copy-resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html), it says this about `<encoding>`:

> The character encoding scheme to be applied when filtering resources.

If you are not doing filtering, the `resources` plugin will simply do a byte-for-byte copy. If you want it to *transform* the resources using the specified encoding, you need to enable filtering, even though you aren't using property interpolation.

**EDITED:**

I just confirmed it. The specified encoding is used both when reading **and** writing the file, which seems counter-intuitive. If you take a look at line 144 in `DefaultMavenFileFilter.java` in the dependency chain of `maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1`:

```
143     fileReader = getFileReader( encoding, from );
144     fileWriter = getFileWriter( encoding, to );
145     Reader src = readerFilter.filter( fileReader, true, wrappers );
146
147     IOUtil.copy( src, fileWriter );
```

When I changed the encoding of `getFileWriter()` to `UTF-8` while debugging, it worked as one would expect.

Basically, you have a couple of options:

- Write your own plugin. It's not that hard for this type of use-case.
- File an improvement ticket (I am thinking about doing this myself if you don't) with the maintainers to introduce an `<outputEncoding>` configuration parameter.
- If you're in a pinch, create your own fork of the plugin. Obviously it would be great if you could contribute your work to the main development stream.

Comment: Been there tried that, with <filtering>true</filtering> under <resource> the copied files are still in UTF-8. This also contradicts with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327003/wrong-encoding-after-activating-resource-filtering. I otherwise completely agree with you on the documentation :)

Comment: I got it to work, sort of. I had a text file with Swedish diacritics in ISO-8859-1 and used your configuration to copy it using UTF-8. It obviously touched file, but the result wasn't what I expected (it applied the UTF-8 encoding while _reading_ the file). I'll run the plugin in the debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: Please see my latest **EDITED** section above.

Comment: Wow that's some hardcore discovery, I'll try to post on their issue tracker

Comment: Posted as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOURCES-232, thanks again for figuring this out!

Comment: Developer here, I have modified the issue off a bug because it isn't one. The mojo is `copy-resources` and not `convert-resources` (`iconv`) style. It would probably make sense to have something like this.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the prompt response. I agree that it isn't a bug, but a nice-to-have feature since the mojo is indeed reading and (re)writing the resource file.

Comment: @Daniel Attention, this mojo is solely for copying resources no more, no less. I am inclined to have a `transform-resources`. `copy-resources` would be a simpler case for the former: `encoding` and `outputEncoding`.

Comment: @Michael-O Absolutely, I am a big fan of _separation of concerns_. It makes more sense to have separate mojos for this.

Comment: @tribbloid If you still need this, please change your issue accordingly.