# maven 3.9.1 failing to build project with error: `filtering {file} to {file} failed with MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 -> [Help 1]`

Tags: java, character-encoding, maven-3, binaryfiles, resource-files

I'm trying to build an existing Java project on my local machine, but it's not working since I upgraded Maven on this machine from 3.8.x to 3.9.1 yesterday. The error message I get is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) on project {project-name}: filtering {project root dir}\app\src\main\resources\{name of binary file} to {project root dir}\app\target\classes\{name of binary file} failed with MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 -> [Help 1]
```

when running the simple command `mvn` or `mvn -e` in the project root directory.

And the full stack trace is as follows:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) on project {project-name}: filtering {project root dir}\app\src\main\resources\{name of binary file} to {project root dir}\app\target\classes\{name of binary file} failed with MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) on project {project-name}: filtering {project root dir}\app\src\main\resources\{name of binary file} to {project root dir}\app\target\classes\{name of binary file} failed with MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:827)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:195)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: filtering {project root dir}\app\src\main\resources\{name of binary file} to {project root dir}\app\target\classes\{name of binary file} failed with MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute (ResourcesMojo.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:827)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:195)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException: filtering {project root dir}\app\src\main\resources\{name of binary file} to {project root dir}\app\target\classes\{name of binary file} failed with MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile (DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources (DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:277)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute (ResourcesMojo.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:827)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:195)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException (CoderResult.java:274)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead (StreamDecoder.java:339)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read (StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read (InputStreamReader.java:181)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read1 (BufferedReader.java:210)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read (BufferedReader.java:287)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill (BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read (BufferedReader.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.BoundedReader.read (BoundedReader.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.read (MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.java:235)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.read (MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.java:197)
    at java.io.Reader.read (Reader.java:229)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge (IOUtils.java:1432)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge (IOUtils.java:1411)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy (IOUtils.java:1208)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.FilteringUtils.copyFile (FilteringUtils.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile (DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources (DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:277)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute (ResourcesMojo.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:827)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:195)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

I'm on Windows 10 Enterprise, Version 21H2. Java version is Amazon Corretto jdk17.0.6_10. (I also have Corretto jdk11.0.18_10 installed, but I'm pretty sure that the 17.x JDK is what's actually being used.)

Other software versions I'm using with the project:

- Apache Tomcat 9.0.70
- NodeJS v14.21.3
- NPM v6.14.18
- NVS (Node Version Switcher) v1.5.2
- Gulp-CLI version 2.3.0
- IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 Ultimate Edition (though I get the same error whether I run maven via IntelliJ or not)

It looks like the error has something to do with Maven 3.9.x trying to interpret a binary resource file as text, and then complaining that the encoding isn't valid. Not sure why it's trying to interpret this file as text. Did something change in that regard in Maven 3.9.0, or something?

I looked at related questions, and tried a variation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26226445) to one of them, but no luck. I'm still getting encoding-related errors.

I have colleagues that use macOS. And our production servers are Linux. Hence, the solution to this problem will need to work on all three platforms.

I tried running `mvn` and `mvn -e`, both directly from the command line (PowerShell) and via IntelliJ IDEA. I got pretty much the same results regardless.

I expected the code to build, and the website to work when run locally, as it has for me in the past. Instead, I got the above error during the Maven build process.

Have considered using an older version of Maven. I don't really like that idea, however, since older Maven versions might have known security vulnerabilities. If needed, I can roll back to Maven v3.8.8 or something. Just want to make sure I understand the problem and what I need to do about it, first.

Comment: maybe change `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0` to `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0`.

Comment: It looks like you are filtering a binary file which you shouldn't... It might be necessary to prevent filtering particular files (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/binaries-filtering.html)

Comment: @khmarbaise your solution worked! I was not explicitly filtering binary files with the extension in question, but neither was I excluding them from being filtered. Making the latter change allowed my project to build successfully with Maven 3.9.1.

Feel free to propose this as an answer, and I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are filtering a binary file which you shouldn't... It might be necessary to prevent filtering particular files (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/binaries-filtering.html)

Comment: Thanks. Can you go ahead and include the sample code from that link, inline, as well?