# tomcat-maven-plugin with multi module and war overlay

Tags: maven, war, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have a maven war project (call it **projectA**) that depends on another maven war (call it **projectB**).  They get integrated using an overlay with the  `maven-war-plugin`.  Both projects have the same parent and the same aggregator (different from the parent).  I can package the final war successfully without any issue.  This is the command I'm running to do that (I'm at the aggregator level when running `mvn`):

```
mvn -am -pl projectA package
```

The reactor build order is **parent** ➡ **projectB** ➡ **projectA** and all is fine.

I'm now trying to use the `tomcat-maven-plugin` in this build.  So I added the `tomcat-maven-plugin` in the parent pom `pluginManagement` section and used it in the **projectA** pom.  I'm launching tomcat with:

```
mvn -am -pl projectA tomcat:run
```

The reactor build order remains the same.  But the tomcat execution is run on **projectB** (which is also a war) and **not** on **projectA**.  Actually, **projectA** build is not even reached.

I've tried with both the org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat-maven-plugin v1.1 and org.apache.tomcat.maven.tomcat6-maven-plugin v2.1, I've found the same behavior.

How can I make tomcat run the final **projectA**?

**Note:** The project dependencies are in fact a bit more complicated and there are other sub-projects involved (jars), that's why I'm calling maven with `-am` (*also make*).

Comment: Just a quick thought, try a _install_ instead of _package_ in your first mvn call...

Comment: Have you configured the [path](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-war-mojo.html#path)?

Comment: Wow ! You mean a war depends on a war ? Quite a strange configuration ! I guess that Maven / tomcat-maven-plugin is itself lost between which war it should use.

Comment: @Dan Yes, if I first do a `mvn install -am -pl projectB` and then a `mvn tomcat:run -pl projectA` it works fine.  I'm still wondering, though, if there would be a way to do that in a single run/step, but maybe it's pointless.

Comment: @CharleeChitsuk I'm not setting any special configuration so far.  But if I try setting the `path` to be that of **projectA**, it's still launches the **projectB** war.  Actually, I'd need to disable completely the `tomcat-maven-plugin` for **projectB**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution.  It is to disable the `maven-tomcat-plugin` for the **pojectB**, this answer is based on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800647/in-a-maven-multi-module-project-how-can-i-disable-a-plugin-in-one-child).

### Linking the plugin to a specific phase

First I had to link the `maven-tomcat-plugin` to a phase of my build cycle, so that it is called even if I don't call the plugin directly from the CLI, obviously I choose the `integration-test` phase.  I can now run `mvn integration-test -pl projectA` to have tomcat being launched with the just build war.

This is how the plugin is declared in the **parent**:

```
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
       <execution>
           <id>run-war</id>
           <!-- We link this plugin to some non default phase so that we can disable it in some modules. -->
           <phase>integration-test</phase>
           <goals>
               <goal>run-war</goal>
           </goals>
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

and in **projectA** I just make use of it as declared in the **parent**:

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
</plugin>
</build>
```

### Deactivating the plugin in projectB

Then, in `projectB`, I link the same plugin (with the same `id`) to a null/void/empty phase, which ends up disabling the plugin for this project when built for this `integration-test` phase:

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>run-war</id>
            <!-- We don't want this plugin to be called from another module build -->
            <phase/>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

With that setup, I can now do a complete build (both projectB, projectA and other dependencies) and launch tomcat with the resulting war in a single run:

```
mvn -am -pl projectA clean integration-test
```