# How to override Maven 3.0 parent plugin properties from child pom

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have maven-war-plugin in parent.pom in that I have set manifestFile property but for one of my war I need to exclude the manifest File under my META-INF.

I added the property </manifestFile> configuration of my war plugin in the child pom but it does not work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Child plugin configurations override parent plugin configurations, but if the configuration is on a parent plugin execution and not on the plugin itself, you can only override it in a corresponding child execution. You do that by creating an execution on the child with the same id as in the parent. If that wasn't clear, try posting the relevant configuration, and we might be able to give a more complete explanation. [My answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7800764/839646) might help you understand.