# In a Maven multi-module project, how can I run a full build and run a specific plugin on one child?

Tags: maven, multi-project

I have a multi-project maven project. One child only has a specific plugin and I want it to be optional (so not bound to a specific phase).
How can I run a full clean install on the entire project and additionally run a project's specific plugin?

I've encountered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800647/in-a-maven-multi-module-project-how-can-i-disable-a-plugin-in-one-child) post but it looks like an overkill, and it is not so easy in my specific case.

Comment: Can you explain what kind of specific plugin is needed in a child only?

Comment: proguard-maven-plugin. I'm not interested in running it on any of the non-final projects nor in the root.

Comment: Than simply define the life cycle binding in that particular child...the version can be defined in parent via pluginManagement...?

Comment: @khmarbaise sorry, I forgot to mention that I do not want the plugin to be bound to a specific phase. I want the hiding to be an optional task

Comment: Sounds like you just need to put plugin invocation into [profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Comment: @rkosegi it sure is the best solution so far. If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: @balsick added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to use [maven build profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

In example, use this snippet in child module:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>only-in-child-module</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                ....
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

This build profile will not be active unless you explicitly ask maven for it like:

`mvn clean install -Ponly-in-child-module`

Comment: yes! that's exactly what I did after reading your comment :) thanks